# Looping through JQUERY using the loop number as the key

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I want to loop through JQUERY based on a count that I would input. Specifically if I enter this for entry 0, this code works:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.0').mouseenter(function()
    {
        $('.hideme0').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('.0').mouseleave(function()
    {
        $('.hideme0').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

I now wish to replace ('.0') Which is dynamic CSS class with the name 0 with a loop counter
for example

```
for (var n = 0; n < 3; ++ n)
{
    $(**n**).mouseenter(function()
    {
        $('.hideme**n**').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $(**n**).mouseleave(function()
    {
        $('.hideme**n**').fadeOut('slow');
    });
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this with jQuery? I can't find info in the API or with a Google search for instructions.

I hope this is clear, and you understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What don't you get? It's just a simple string so you can build it with concatenation:

```
$('.' + n).mouseenter(function()
{
    $('.hideme' + n).fadeIn('slow');
//...
//and so on
```

However, using this in a for loop will like cause an issue due to closures. Which you can solve like so:

```
for (var n = 0; n < 3; ++ n)
{
    (function(x){
        $('.' + x).mouseenter(function()
        {
            $('.hideme' + x).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    })(n);

    (function(x){
        $('.' + x).mouseleave(function()
        {
            $('.hideme' + x).fadeOut('slow');
        });
    })(n);
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7R8X4/3/) using your HTML (from comments)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I really appreciate it but this solution didn't work for me unfortunately. Thanks anyway

Comment: @StephenKennedy: What part doesn't work? Do you get any console errors? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Hi, I'm debugging it now musefan, its a pain! Can you include the code including the $(document).ready() element? I'm wondering now if I'm just doing something crazy. First I thought my PHP might be causing the error but its working fine if I don't loop it, if I just set them up one by one.

Comment: @StephenKennedy: Create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the HTML and I will make the javascript work with it, then you can see it in action

Comment: Hi, I made a JSFIDDLE, http://jsfiddle.net/7R8X4/, but its useless without access to the mysql DB I think..

Comment: @StephenKennedy: YEah that useless, I just wanted your output HTML, not the PHP stuff. Can you run the page and then copy the HTML from page source (right click > view source)

Comment: Yeah thats better!http://jsfiddle.net/7R8X4/ Thats a handy tool alright, JS Fiddle! Now in the page, when you scroll over the boxes with borders, you should get a box fading in and fading out

Comment: @StephenKennedy: You need to "Update" it so I can see the changes, you will get a new URL like: http://jsfiddle.net/7R8X4/1

Comment: Hi Musefan, thanks a bunch, can you repost that link? It seems to be broken, I'm getting a 'Error 404
We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.'

Comment: @StephenKennedy: You need to make that link. The new fiddle with your just HTML code, you need to press "Update" to generate a new link so I can see it... then I can fix it and send you a new link back

Comment: Apologies, updated now http://jsfiddle.net/7R8X4/2/

Comment: My code works exactly as I posted: [See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/7R8X4/3/)

Comment: Musefan, you are the man! I don't know why it didn't work initially for me, maybe I didn't have the $(document).ready in the right place or something..anyway kudos. Thanks, you've made my day. You probably don't need coding tips from me, but if you ever need help, give me a shout

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var n = 0; n < 3; n++)
{
    $("." + n).mouseenter(function()
    {
        $('.hideme' + n).fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $("." + n).mouseleave(function()
    {
        $('.hideme'+ n).fadeOut('slow');
    });
}
```

Comment: should be `$("." + n)`

Comment: you caught it while I was editing. thanks.

Comment: Hi All, thanks very much for getting back. Still not working:for         (var n = 0; n < 20; n++)
    {
    $('.' + n).mouseenter(function()
    {
        $('.hideme' + n).fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $('.' + n).mouseleave(function()
    {
        $('.hideme'+ n).fadeOut('slow');
    });
} This is the code I'm currently using. I checked in my comments on my js page and I had actually already tried this.

Comment: does the console produce an error?

Comment: No error, the fadin and fadeout just don't seem to happen, I'm debugging now...thanks again for trying to help

Comment: add console.log or an alert to mouseenter and mouseleave too see if they fire. if they don't try $( ...).bind("mouseenter", function()...

Comment: Hi Mark, they are firing indeed, I have alerts popping up now, it looks like now the n from $('.' + n).mouseenter(function() and the n from $('.hideme' + n).fadeIn('slow'); have different values, the internal $('.hideme' + n).fadeIn('slow'); n is producing the number I'm looping to (the last iteration of the loop) when I fire an alert with n.

Answer (score 1):

You can just concatenate the string and use that as your selector:

```
var index = 1;
var selector = '.hideme' + index;
$(selector).fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

It should just be a matter of concatenating the number value as part of the selector string:

```
$('.' + n).mouseenter(function()
{
    $('.hideme' + n).fadeIn('slow');
});
$('.' + n).mouseleave(function()
{
    $('.hideme' + n).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Numerics can be interpreted as strings implicitly in JavaScript in this manner.